# How to properly format terraform (HCL) code

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, code-formatting

There's insufficient documentation on which code language identifier to use for the terraform language.

The expected values (`tf`, `hcl`, or `terraform`) do not work.

Is this supported, and if so, what is the correct language identifier?

Comment: The canonical list is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) (also linked from [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)). When in doubt, "lang-tagName" always works. In this case, there does not appear to be any syntax highlighting for HCL. The [[tag:hcl]] tag has its associated syntax highlighting set to "<none>", so any highlighting you're seeing is just coming from "default" (i.e., Prettify's language-neutral best-guess attempt).

Comment: @CodyGray- What would be the steps then of getting the `hcl` tag to match `lang-hcl`? I get that hcl might not have a perfect highlighter but if the default is better than none, should the `hcl` be aligned with `default`, thereby getting the improved behavior of `lang-hcl`?

Comment: added the `bug` tag because the intentional behavior of using no formatting on `hcl` code hint seems worse than applying the default (which we get via `lang-hcl`).

Comment: Yes, I can update the [[tag:hcl]] tag to force the "default" formatting to be used. Done now. See if that makes a difference on the posts without explicit formatting hints.

Comment: Awesome! I added a sample below in my answer. Will refresh periodically and post back shortly when it's had time to replicate.

Comment: The default hinting won't ever work on Meta. You'll have to check the main site. The default hinting is set per-tag, and Meta uses different tags.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I've put three versions of the code block on my related Answer on the main site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628749/set-terraform-default-interpreter-for-local-exec/61392460#61392460 The first block is `hcl`, second block is `lang-hcl`, third block is default (no tag). As of right now, just the middle block (`lang-hcl`) is formatting as expected.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's because that question has the [[tag:terraform]] tag, not the [[tag:hcl]] tag. I will update the default syntax highlighting for the [[tag:terraform]] tag, too. This can sometimes confuse the syntax highlighter, which is why we don't make "default" the actual default. That mostly happens in cases where questions have multiple tags, and each of their default syntax highlighting rules conflict with each other. So let me know if you see any issues with this, and it can be reversed.

Comment: It works now - awesome! I actually did not realize at all that the tag on the question could affect the default code formatter. Although in hindsight now it seems obvious. :) Anyway, THANK YOU for your help! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

By performing a browser `inspect` on one correctly-formatted answer, we can see that `lang-hcl` is the identifier which works properly.

Using `lang-hcl` (works):

```hcl
provider "aws" {
  # Sample
  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

---

**For reference:**

Using `hcl` (doesn't work):

```
provider "aws" {
  # Sample
  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

Using no hint (doesn't work):

```
provider "aws" {
  # Sample
  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the comment is not formatted correctly in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231330/2023941