# HCL language for code block

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

It is possible to ask for a new language to be available for code blocks? If yes, I feel that adding the `hcl` language identifier would be handy. There is a similar [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396915/how-to-properly-format-terraform-hcl-code) somebody ask not too long ago and the solution they found is to have the `lang-hlc` identifier, which help, but it is actually a generic one that does not take into account the latter part of the identifier.

Lastly, I cannot find the list of available language identifier. Is such list available?

Comment: HCL is not in the [list of supported languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), the answer you link is probably from when Prettify was used for syntax highlighting.

Comment: List of language codes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/141193

Comment: I first encountered this list before asking my question, but I wasn't sure if it was maintained. I understand now that I can safely assume it is.